# Dados php e marcadores google maps

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Possuo um `foreach` pegando alguns dados do banco, entre eles o endereço.

```
foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneio) as $dados) {
   echo $dados->getRomaneio() . " - ";
   echo $dados->getPlaca() . " - ";
   echo $dados->getCte() . " - ";
   echo ($roteiro->FormataData($dados->getDtSaidaRomaneio())) . " - ";
   echo $dados->getEndereco() . " <br> ";
}
```

Sáida:

```
15317 - ITU-9637 - 12-5162 - 21/11/2016 - RUA ALVORADA-29, - VILA RUTE - GUARULHOS - SP, 7054080 
15317 - ITU-9637 - 12-5251 - 21/11/2016 - RUA CABO ANTÔNIO PEREIRA DA SILVA-307, - JARDIM TRANQUILIDADE - GUARULHOS - SP, 7051011
```

A minha idéia é a seguinte, tendo estes dados do endereço, gostaria de lançar estes endereços como marcadores no google maps para facilitar a visualização, cada endereço um marcador.

Estou usando uma classe JS.

```
<script src="js/gmaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/markers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script>
    $(function () {

        //Definir o centro do mapa 
        initMap('Endereço aqui');

        //Adicionar marcadores
        addMarker('Endereço aqui');
        addMarker('Endereço aqui');

    })
</script>
```

Minha pergunta é: Como consigo pegar os dados que recebo no `getEndereco` e por dentro do `addMarker` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo deste jeito. Não sei se é o melhor porém está funcional.

```
<script>
   $(function () {

      initMap('Av. Paulista, 500, São Paulo, SP', 'map');

      <?php foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneio) as $dados) { ?>
          addMarker('<?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?>');
      <?php } ?>
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basta adicionar dentro do Foreach a função.

> foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneio) as $dados) {
>
> echo $dados->getRomaneio() . " - ";
>
> echo $dados->getPlaca() . " - ";
>
> echo $dados->getCte() . " - ";
>
> echo ($roteiro->FormataData($dados->getDtSaidaRomaneio())) . " - ";
>
> echo $dados->getEndereco() . " 
>  ";
>
> > **addMarker('Endereço aqui');**
>
> }

Caso utilize uma função não nativa do google maps, deve se criar uma função para o add marker.

> function addMarker(endereco){
>    **AQUI ADICIONA A FUNÇÃO DE ADICIONAR O MARCADOR! NEW MARKER**
>   };